# How do you add a 100ms delay to all IP traffic from a Solaris 9 box?

Tags: solaris

I need to add 100ms delay to all IP traffic from my Solaris 9 box. How do I do it?

Best Regards

Howard

Comment: Switch to NT. BAM - traffic delay.

Comment: Interesting. And most people are trying to *speed up* their servers.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps take a look at [Trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle)?

Answer (score 1):

How about tweaking QOS?  I think that might work, but if you gave some background as to what you are trying to accomplish, you may get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have previously used [netem](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem) to simulate slow/wan/variable links for application testing between solaris hosts. Works really well.

You'll need a linux box though.